# MySql updating a table using only a single select query

Tags: mysql

I update `table_b`, with data from `table_a`, like below.

```
table_a

"id"    "addedUser" "addedName"
"1"     "1"         "james"
"2"     "1"         "kirk"
"3"     "1"         "lars"
"4"     "2"         "michael"

update table_b set 
totalFriends = 20, #data I supply
totalRequests = 20, #data I supply
userDisplay = (select addedName from table_a where addedUser = 1 limit 1), 
userFriends = (select group_concat(addedName) from table_a where addedUser = 1 limit 1) 
where 
userId = 1 and userName = 'norman';

table_b

"id"    "userId"    "userName"  "userDisplay"   "userFriends"               "totalFriends"  "totalRequests"
"1"     "1"         "norman"    "james"         "james,kirk,lars"   "20"            "20"
```

I run the sql above, which gives me results I'm looking for. Except, can I do this in some other way so as to avoid using two select statements in there?

The actual thing is whole lot more complicated than this. I've stripped things down for this question.

Comment: How do you get michael as an added friend?

Comment: Apologies, the Sql was wrong. I've updated the question with the correct sql.

Comment: Okay, but Michael is still not in that criteria, right?

Comment: No, he isn't. Michael is friend of user 2

Comment: Okay, you have him listed in 'userFriends' which is what threw me. I have edited my answer based on your edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is write a select statement that has some constant values where you have them already (for the data you supply). For example, you can write this statement:

```
SELECT addedName AS userDisplay, GROUP_CONCAT(addedName) AS userFriends, 20 AS totalFriends, 20 AS totalRequests
FROM table_a
WHERE addedUser = 1
LIMIT 1;
```

Then, you can use that in your UPDATE statement like this:

```
UPDATE table_b b
JOIN(
  SELECT addedUser, addedName AS userDisplay, GROUP_CONCAT(addedName) AS userFriends, 20 AS totalFriends, 20 AS totalRequests
  FROM table_a
  WHERE addedUser = 1
  LIMIT 1) temp ON temp.addedUser = b.userid
SET
  b.totalFriends = temp.totalFRiends,
  b.totalRequests = temp.totalRequests,
  b.userDisplay = temp.userDisplay,
  b.userFriends = temp.userFriends
WHERE b.userid = 1 AND b.username = 'Norman';
```

It worked for me in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f071c/1).